# Automating enabling and disabling specific services for brief maintenance windows

Tags: linux, service, maintenance

For short periods of time (generally measured in seconds or minutes), I need to enable ftp (`vsftpd`) access on a webserver hosting WordPress so that plugins, themes, etc can be updated via the WP administrative dashboard.

Currently, I initiate an ssh session, enable `vsftpd`, run the update from wordpress, disable `vsftpd`, and logout.

Such maintenance activities are done on an *ad hoc* basis, as and when updates are made available - and not necessarily on a specific maintenance cycle (for exploit/bug fixes, new features, etc).

What would be some viable routes to automate the enabling and disabling of the ftp server in this scenario?

Comment: Isn't that precisely what shell scripts are for?

Comment: @ErikA - absolutely: the issue is how to do it via a remote trigger when an update needs to happen, ie without having ssh access to the host. Linking a shell script execution to a web page (*a la* PHP), would seem to be a pretty big security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try achieving this using xinetd

Check man xinetd.conf
and
[setup example](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/4505/4)